# Revocation of Master Degree

Tags: thesis, masters

I didn't give the dimensions of the machine that I designed in my master thesis. My supervisor said that you don't need to give dimensions and said that they are useless for a thesis: you don't make a design as an engineer, you are doing research. So I didn't share the dimensions. And I have dimension-related findings/figures in my thesis. I mean, if you change dimensions, half of the graphs/results need to be revised. But now, I learned that some people say that it makes your thesis misrepresent. Is it the case for my thesis?

On the other hand, I spent three long years for this thesis and I never plagiarised. I asked every question to my supervisor. But today because of this situation I'm very stressed. I didn't want to a mistake but because of my supervisor's reckless situation I don't know if it will cause my thesis to be revoked :(

You can imagine that; in 80% of my study I have 2 data sets: one of them subject data the other one is my design. So, you can't change the subject data I mean they are constant numbers and also I give reference to that data. But my design's dimensions can be changed and if you change them all my figures are changed because the structure is changed. Can you make a comment on this situation please?

Comment: Welcome to AC.SE. Please take a look at our [help]. We are aware of your edits and your desire for the question to attract more attention. Unfortunately, the community doesn't think your question is a great fit. it is hard for me to find the question within the long narrative. I suggest you distill the text down to the core question.

Comment: "Can you make a comment on this situation please?" is not a good question for this site.

Answer (score 7):

Your thesis should not be revoked for not including the dimensions of the machine. You haven't attempted to deliberately misrepresent or misstate things—you and your advisor made a decision something wasn't relevant to the thesis.

But I honestly don't see why your thesis *shouldn't* include the dimensions of the machine. If it's relevant for establishing a comparison between the existing data and yours, then it really is essential to the thesis and should be included, at least as an appendix. Your own comments suggest that the information is necessary for the reader to process and understand your figures.

If your thesis has already been submitted and approved, don't worry about it. If it's in the revision stages, talk to your advisor about why you feel it should be included.

Comment: It should be obvious to someone in your field that if you change the relative physical dimensions, the results will likely change. Given that, you shouldn't worry about revocation of the thesis. But like I said, it wouldn't hurt to stick a table with the dimensions you used _somewhere_ (in a future paper, in a revision of the thesis, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have any issues as long as your advisor is happy. The thesis should be accepted and the degree awarded. After that it is up to you whether you want to publish based on the thesis and what you say.

You can certainly revise and extend anything in the thesis. Just cite it appropriately. But for now, just make your advisor happy.

Comment: You should be fine. Time to relax and have a beverage suitable to your culture. Your English works fine, by the way, if not perfect.