# Revocation of Master's Degree

Tags: thesis

My question was answered in following link actually, because of that, thank you.

(you don't need to look at following link it is for understanding to story)=[Revocation of Master Degree](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/122763/revocation-of-master-degree)

But i need to to revise my question because, yesterday, my advisor confessed that; if you had given the dimensions of prosthetic arm, it could be produced very easily by looking your thesis and dimensions. You gave the spring coefficients, motor spec, described the mechanisms etc.

And on the other hand he said that; "I want to commercialize the prosthetic arm so, I wanted you not to share dimensions. They are actually important for the design and also for your thesis as you know. But if you had shared the dimensions, other people could use our design"   So I don't know what to do now... I had never felt worse than today :( Can it cause to my degree revocation?

information about the need of dimensions; we didn't give the dimensions of the prosthetic arm that I designed in my master thesis. My supervisor said not to share detailed technical drawing by giving dimensions. We shared as visual in thesis. So I didn't share the dimensions. And I have dimension-related findings/figures in my thesis. I mean, if you change dimensions, the graphs/results need to be revised. But you can not find dimensions by looking graphs/results. But now, I learned that some people say that it makes your thesis misrepresent. Is it the case for my thesis? Thank you

Comment: After seeing that you have asked several related question, I must ask, why are you so afraid of degree revocation? That is a very rare ocurrence.

Comment: People have constantly told you here that there is nothing to worry about and there is high certainty that your degree will not be revoked. Degrees are revoked for big issues and academic dishonesty, like falsification of key data, or plagiarism of large/key portions. To me it seems that you have an irrational fear of revocation.

Comment: As Massimo said, the issue is deliberate behavior. You have done nothing wrong and have nothing to worry about. Your advisor hid his motivations and plans from you. That should be much more concerning to you than fearing your degree will be revoked.

Comment: "...i mean he never minded my thesis and my study". Why do you say that if he wants to commercialize this prosthetic arm (that I guess you made)? It seems that he is on the contrary quite happy with it no?
"I learned that some people say that it makes your thesis misrepresent" where did you hear that ? As the other said, your thesis will not be revoked if you omitted (intentionally or not) some dimensions, especially if your advisor told you to do so ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly answering your question, but there is one option that might be of interest. Some universities (at least in my country) allow for theses to be blocked, i.e. not published in any university archive, for a certain amount of time (5 years max. at my university). This is intended for cases, where material of a thesis is in preparation for submission to a journal or if results are in the process of getting commercialized or a patent application was made.

You might ask at your university if such an option exists, which would make the content of your thesis confidential. And in turn, this could make your supervisor less worried about any disclosed details. However, from what I understand you have already submitted your thesis, thus the university would have to retroactively initiate such a process, which might not be possible at all.